# Trying to compare PDO statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am grabbing two random rows from my table. I then want to compare them to make sure that they are not the same rows. If they are I want to keep selecting a random row until I get on that is not the same.

Currently I am selecting random rows fine my issue comes up when I hit the while loop trying to get a different row. I get the following error "Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object"

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $cycles; $i++) {
        $t1 = $dbtemp->query("SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
        $t2 = $dbtemp->query("SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
        $winner = $t1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $loser = $t2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($winner['id'] == $loser['id']) {
            while($winner['id'] == $loser['id']) {
                $t2 = $dbtemp->query("SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
                $loser = $t2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Error occurs on this line
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions on how I should or could go about making this work would be great.

Comment: Which line does the error point?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos See the comment.

Comment: `$t2` apparently is `FALSE`. Please set `$dbtemp->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` before executing any query and catch the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do like this:

```
$t1 = $dbtemp->query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
```

And then:

```
$players = $t1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$winner = $players[0];
$loser = $players[1];
```

Comment: +1 for [**KISS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) Keep It Simple Stupid

Comment: @davidstrachan speaking of simplicity, I am curious, if anyone noticed the *for loop* outside. And the while loop inside.

Comment: @YourCommonSense KISS for Answer.No need for for loop.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - for loop is there because this is all part of a function that is sent a variable telling it how many times to complete this task. I included it because I thought it might be important in figuring out what was causing the error i was getting.